# Generating Map from Map of Maps using Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I have a Map of Maps in the format

```
Map < Integer, Map < String, Integer >>
```

If I have data in the format of

```
<1>, << X, 11 >, < Y, 13 >, < Z, 15 >>
<2>, << X,12 >, < A, 23 >, < L, 41 >>
```

How to process this using Java 8 lambda and generate the following

```
<1>, <[11, 13, 15]>
<2>, <[12, 23, 41]>
```

That is generate another Map where the key is the key of the outer map and the value is a List of the values of the inner Map. I know how to do this in the regular way but I am looking at how this using Java 8 Lambda.

Comment: Do you mean using Streams with lambdas? If not, what did you do "the regular way" and how do you hope to convert it to lambdas?

Comment: Java-8 has not only introduce Lambda. Stream and Method Reference can help you to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` to recreate a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` :

```
input.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(),
                                          e->new ArrayList(e.getValue().values())));
```

In this piece of code, we collect the `Entry<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` into a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` by transforming them so that the value becomes the `List<Integer>` of values of the inner map, while the key stays the same.

You can test it [here](https://ideone.com/fwIb0T).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.